# Add or update entity in EF Core

Tags: c#, database, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have an entity with a recursive relationship like:

```cs
public class Message {
   [Key]
   public int MessageId { get; set; }

   public int? ReplyToMessageId { get; set; }

   public Message ReplyToMessage { get; set; }

   public ICollection<Message> ReplyMessages { get; set; }
}
```

JSON data:
`{ "messages": [ { "id": 1, "reply_to": null, "replied_messages": [ { "id": 2, "reply_to": 1, "replied_messages": [] }, { "id": 3, "reply_to": 1, "replied_messages": [] } ] } ] }`

I create an instance of the message(id 1) and replied messages(id 2,3,4) from JSON data and add the replies(id 2,3,4) to message(id 1) as ReplyMessages, also, the message(id 1) already exist in the database

I need to have an add or update method to save the messages
So i write following code:

```cs
public void AddOrUpdate(Message message) {
  if(Context.Messages.Any(m => m.MessageId == message.MessageId))
    Context.Messages.Update(message);
  else
    Context.Messages.Add(message);
    Context.SaveChanges();
}
```

This method make an exception when I pass an existing message with a collection of new replied messages

> Database operation expected to affect 1 row(s) but actually affected 0 row(s). Data may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded.

I test `BulkMerge` method of the `Entity Framework Extensions` library and it's work fine but I'm looking for a solution with ef core without any extension

More Information:

```
Database Provider: Postgresql
EF Core Version: 5.0.2
```

Comment: Can you show how message is initialized before `AddOrUpdate`?

Comment: Can you also show the exception?

Comment: Can you show a json example?

Comment: What is the provider? MySql?

Comment: FYI `Context.Messages.Update` already has add or update functionality. No need for you to make the distinction. Further, please always add new info to the question, not as comment, and please tag the EF version you're using.

Comment: @GertArnold I tested Update method without any existing check and get a similar exception and also the exception raised from the Update method because the message(A) already existed, Further, when I edit my question StackOverflow notify you?

Comment: It seems like ef core tracking issue.

Comment: @Batuhan you are right i set QueryTrackingBehavior to NoTracking, now the problem solved, thank

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like ef core tracking issue. If you add `AsNoTracking()` to `query` locally or globally, commenting may solve the issue.

Also without changing tracking behaviour you can try something like this:

```
context.Entry(Message).CurrentValues.SetValues(changed_message_model);
```

Comment: @alireza This is totally meaningless without seeing the code where tracking behavior applies. It's more likely that your context lifecycle management isn't right and it's time to fix *that* instead of applying a poor patch by disabling tracking. Next time you save the *same* message you'll probably get this error again.

Comment: @GertArnold the issue shown when I use AsNoTracking, I don't say to disabling tracking, it means if you disable tracking you make this problem

Comment: Well, then the answer isn't really clear. It's a long shot anyway. Your code doesn't reveal anything of how you make a complete roundtrip database-client-database. The JSON suggests it's a disconnected scenario in which tracking doesn't play a role in this roundtrip and `SetValues` can't be done without first re-fetching the entity from the database -- *if* you indeed have short-lived contexts as recommended.